# approximating a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am given $f\in C[a,b]$, I need to prove an existance of a polynomial $p$
such that $p(a)=f(a),p'(a)=0$ and $|p(x)-f(x)<\epsilon \forall x\in [a,b]$

I know stone-weirstrass theorem, but how can I apply here this?

Comment: Taylor Series approximation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Polynomials in $(x-a)^2$ are dense in $C([a,b])$ by Stone-Weierstrass.